# Best Characteristic to predict the price of a car

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

I want to compare all parameters of cars at once using .corr() function to know what is the best parameter to predict the price of a car but I don't know how to include all parameters at once. In the last line of my code how to include all parameters?

My Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.read_csv (r'/home/heisenberg/Downloads/CarPrice_Assignment.csv')
print(df.columns)
print(df['price'])


sns.regplot(x = "highwaympg", y="price", data=df)
plt.ylim(0,)
plt.show()
print(df[['enginesize', 'highwaympg', 'price']].corr())
```

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for your kind information sir.